# In a Django template, how do I access attributes of a dict element whose key has a space?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `dict` of forms that my template receives:

```
forms = {'Cholera': CholeraForm(), 'Foot And Mouth Disease': FootMouthDiseaseForm()}
```

The plan is to display each key in a `select` form element, and depending on the value selected, I'll show the correct form. Accessing `dict` elements that have spaces in the key is a simple enough problem, solved by a template tag:

```
@register.filter
def get(value, arg):
    """
            Template tag used for getting the value out of a dict when the key has whitespace.
    """
    return value[arg]
```

This allows me to get the form like this:

```
{{ forms|get:'Foot And Mouth Disease' }}
```

However, a problem I'm experiencing is that I can't access specific form elements. I would hope to be able to do this:

```
{{ forms|get:'Foot And Mouth Disease'.element }}
```

or this:

```
{{ (forms|get:'Foot And Mouth Disease').element }}
```

But neither work. I get TemplateSyntaxErrors on each. How can I access a particular form element of a form accessed in this manner?

Comment: I think the template will render the form in html.  It might be best to assign each form to a different variable or perform any logic within the views.py if you only plan to display one specific form for that page.

Comment: I'm definitely open to doing that, but I'm not really sure how. The view doesn't know which form it will be displaying. The basic idea is that the user of this app can select a disease, and depending on the disease they select, a different set of questions should be asked.

Comment: It can be done the regular html page by page way where selecting a specific disease will redirect to another page with that specific form.  Alternatively, you can use some ajax to dynamically change the form on the same page.  Whichever one your requirement needs or you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I think I may look into the AJAX way of doing it. That ought to be more elegant and should solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I might slugify the form's title when building the dict, and then de-slugify it on the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with`:

```
{{ with forms|get:'Foot And Mouth Disease' as item }}
{{ item.element }}
{{ endwith }}
```

But a better way might be to change your filter into an assignment tag, which adds the item into the context directly.